# Why is CursorAdapter different from BaseAdapter?

Tags: android, baseadapter, android-cursoradapter

I would like to ask why `CursorAdapter` splits the process of creating a view and populating it with data into `newView()` and `bindView()` while `BaseAdapter` only does this with `getView()`  ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From Source code of [CursorAdapter.java](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/v4/java/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java), `CursorAdapter` extends `BaseAdapter`.
And you can see `getView()` function implementation:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        if (!mDataValid) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("this should only be called when the cursor is valid");
        }
        if (!mCursor.moveToPosition(position)) {
            throw new IllegalStateException("couldn't move cursor to position " + position);
        }
        View v;
        if (convertView == null) {
            v = newView(mContext, mCursor, parent);
        } else {
            v = convertView;
        }
        bindView(v, mContext, mCursor);
        return v;
    }
```

Its do what we usually do in `getView()` (inflate the view if convertView is null, otherwise reuse the view), so its just for make it easier for the developer OR force the user to use ViewHolder pattern.

PS: Some devs calls bindViews() function in there newView() implementation, from the source code you can see there is no need for that.

Comment: CursorAdapter is also closes previous used Cursor (take a look at changeCursor(Cursor) method). This is useful or awful, depending on your case))

Answer (score 2):

If you check [CurosrAdapter](http://grepcode.com/file_/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.3_r2.1/android/support/v4/widget/CursorAdapter.java/?v=source) source code you can see, that in `getView` method, both `newView` and `bindView` methods are used. Method `newView` is executed only when there is no view, thus it can spare the creation of some objects. Method `bindView` is always called and it purpouse is to update view data.