# Getting SQLite row id from ListView with OnLongClickListener not working

Tags: android, sqlite, listview, row, onlongclicklistener

Well, this is the setting:

Code for the activity

```
public class Users_List extends Activity {

    private ArrayList<Users> users;
    private ListView lvusers;
    private int user_selected;
    private DB db;
    private ListAdapter adaptador;
    private static final int NEW_USER = 0;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.users_list);

        DB db = new DB(this);
        users = db.getAllUsers();

        lvusers = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

        adaptador = new AdaptadorUsersList(this, users);

        lvusers.setAdapter(adaptador);
        lvusers.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        registerForContextMenu(lvusers);

        final Button new_user = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_new_user);

        nuevo_socio.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Users_List.this,
                        User_Form.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent, NEW_USER);
            }
        });

        lvusers.setOnItemLongClickListener(new OnItemLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> a, View view, int position, long id) {
                //HERE...LONG ID IS ALWAYS ZERO, WHY???
                Log.d("Selected User--------", "---------------------"+id+"--------");
                openContextMenu(lvusers);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
   //Here the codes continues....
```

}

I readed that the long id param. on onItemLongClick is actually the id of the row that was clicked right? so, what's wrong here that the id is returning always "0" as value on logcat?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

the ID of the `onItemClickListener` or `onItemLongClickListner` is the same as the ID of the row if the adapter extends `CursorAdapter` or `simpleCursorAdapter` because the Cursor will take care of putting the Item's ID to the Long ID.

Bare in mind that your ID column or the primary key field should have the name of "_id". here is an [example](http://chetanandroidarora.wordpress.com/2011/12/18/customcursoradapter/) of how to implement Custom `CursorAdapter`.

**Edit**

You can use `BaseAdapter` as `CursorAdapter` since from the source code of `CursorAdapter` it extends the `BaseAdapter` however you will use getView() to call the `bindView()` and `newView()` where these two functions are the main functions of the `CursorAdapter`

so basically you are doing the `CursorAdapter` from the scratch refer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561744/why-is-cursoradapter-different-from-baseadapter) where they explain it more in details.

hope this answer your question.

Comment: Mine extends from BaseAdapter, how does it work for it? Oh, and thank you for your interest on solving my dumb question!

Comment: It is my pleasure :) please check the edited part and tell me if it is what you are looking for